# ADT Stack with a doubly circular linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, circular-list

I have managed to implement an `ADTStack` with a circular doubly linked list. I would like to know whether there are things I could have done better or, I should improve.

```
public class QueueCircularDLL<T> implements ADTQueue<T> {    
    private ListElement<T> head;
    private ListElement<T> tail;

    public QueueCircularDLL(){
        head=null;
        tail=null;
    }

    public void enq (T element){
        ListElement<T>newElement=new ListElement<T>(element);
        if (empty()){
            head= newElement;
            tail= head;
        }

        tail.setNextElement(newElement);
        newElement.setPrevElement(tail);
        tail=tail.getNextElement();
        tail.setNextElement(head);
        head.setPrevElement(tail);

    }

    public void deq(){
        if (empty()){
            throw new RuntimeException("queue is empty");
        }

        if (head==tail){
            //head=null;
            head=null;
            tail=null;

        }
        else{
        head=head.getNextElement();
        head.setPrevElement(tail);
        tail.setNextElement(head);
        }

    }

    public T front(){
        if(empty()){
            return null;
        }
        return head.getElement();
    }

    public boolean empty(){
        return (head==null);
    }

    private static class ListElement<T>{
        private T element = null;
        private ListElement<T> nextElement = null;
        private ListElement<T> prevElement = null;

        public ListElement(T element) {
            this.element = element;
        }

        public T getElement() {
            return element;
        }

        public ListElement<T> getNextElement() {
            return nextElement;
        }

        public void setNextElement(ListElement<T> element) {
            this.nextElement = element;
        }
        //für zirkuläre doppelt verkettete liste
        public ListElement<T>getPrevElement(){
            return prevElement;
        }
        // für zirkuläre doppelt verkette liste
        public void setPrevElement(ListElement<T> element){
            this.prevElement=element;
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueueCircularDLL<Integer> queue = new QueueCircularDLL<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            queue.enq(i);
        }

        while (!queue.empty()) {
            System.out.println(queue.front());
            queue.deq();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The class doesn't expose a method that let's users benefit from the circular property.
The `enq`, `deq`, `front`, `empty` methods could work just fine without the circular property.
As such, it's an unnecessary complexity.
If you want to use a circular linked list,
then expose some methods that need or benefit from the circular property.

The class `QueueCircularDLL<T>` implements the `ADTQueue<T>` interface,
but it's not clear which methods belong to the interface.
It's strongly recommended to make that clear using the `@Override` annotation.

In `front`, instead of returning `null` when the list is empty,
a more common practice is to throw `java.util.NoSuchElementException`,
as done by the various linked list and queue implementations in the JDK.

Comment: hey, first of all, thx for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

**Constructor needed?**

First of, these are not needed because Java null initializes object references.

```
public QueueCircularDLL(){
    head=null;
    tail=null;
}
```

Meaning, you do not need a constructor in this code.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

*Note: It can be considered bad practice, if you prefer to explicity state they are null then do it in the same line as initialization.*

---

**Code Conventions**

Normally `if-else` would look like:

```
if (statement) {
    // if true
} else {
    // if false
}
```

[Reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#449)

---

**Javadoc**

Almost every programmer out there will tell you to write it before or during development, which can be hard and time-consuming when still learning. However, it is good practice to write it once you are "done" with the code. Gives you some time to reflect upon what you have done.

[Further Read](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html)

Answer (score 0):

- You mix spaces-around-operators styles. Java best practices is to use spaces.
- It's also best practices to prefix names of methods that return a `boolean` with verbs like *is*, *has*, *contains*, ... hence:

  ```
  public boolean isEmpty()
  ```

  Just `empty()` could also mean that something is cleared with the returned `boolean` as indicator for success.
- I do, but I'm not sure whether many others understand the German comments here. :-)